# Fetching multiple details from tables using INNER JOIN - Throws not unique alias error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch the details of all the stakeholders in a competition where I am trying to join the user table to multiple tables where the primary key of user table acts as foreign key in other tables. Here is my table structure for this

When i run the query using inner join then the error thrown is not unique alias and I don't want to have different columns for names of stakeholders if i change the alias

Users -

```
Id - PK 
qrencia_id - varchar
user_email - varchar
password - varchar
role - Enum (Candidate, Judge, Expert)
```

Competitions

```
id - PK
name - varchar
created By - FK (PK of users table)
```

Skills

```
id - PK
skill_name - varchar
```

cs_ip_mapping

```
id - PK
competition_id - FK (PK of competitions table)
skill_id - FK (skill table PK)
user_id - FK (user table PK)
```

cs_ip_expert_mapping

```
id - PK
cs_ip_id - FK (PK of cs_ip_mapping table)
user_expert_id - FK (PK User Table)
```

cs_ip_judge_mapping

```
id - PK
cs_ip_id - FK (PK of cs_ip_mapping table)
user_judge_id - FK (PK User Table)
```

cs_ip_candidate_mapping

```
id - PK
cs_ip_id - FK (PK of cs_ip_mapping table)
user_candidate_id - FK (PK User Table)
```

This is my query:

```
select users.name as name, 
       users.qrencia_id as qrenciaId, 
       c.competition_name as competitionName,
       s.skill as skillName
from competitions as c 
inner join competition_skills_implementation_partner as csip on c.id=csip.competition_id 
inner join skills as s on csip.skills_id=s.id 
inner join users on csip.user_ip_id=users.id 
inner join cs_ip_expert_mapping as expert on csip.id = expert.cs_ip_id 
inner join users as expertUser on expert.user_expert_id=expertUser.id 
inner join cs_ip_judge_mapping as judge on csip.id = judge.cs_id_fk 
inner join users on judge.user_judge_id=users.id 
inner join cs_ip_candidate_mapping as candidate on csip.id=candidate.cs_ip_id
inner join users on users.id=candidate.user_candidate_id
where csip.id=53;
```

The result should be - when I select the skill and competition then all the stakeholders' list should be visible

Comment: What result you are getting from this query?

Comment: Is this line correct - `inner join cs_ip_judge_mapping as judge on csip.id = judge.cs_id_fk `.  Should "`cs_id_fk`" be "`cs_ip_id`"?

Comment: Could you post the full error message as well? Thanks

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Either you want only one user, in which case you need to remove three joins or you want all four user names in the same row, in which case (personally) I would do four subqueries instead.